# How to solve the following SDP with cvxpy in Python?

Tags: python, libraries, semidefinite-programming

The SDP problem is
$$
\min_{Z \in S^{n},Y \in S^{m}} {\rm trace}(Z) +{\rm trace}(Y)\\
{\rm s.t.} \begin{bmatrix}
Y & X\\
X^T & Z
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0\\
X \in C
$$
Where $C$ is a convex set.But I have some difficulty in transforming it to the standard form:
$$
\min_{X}\operatorname{trace}(CX) \\
\text{s.t.} \ \operatorname{trace}(A_{i}X)=b_i,i=1,...,p \\
X\succeq 0
$$
If let $\overline X= \begin{bmatrix}
Y & X\\
X^T & Z
\end{bmatrix}$ ,then the problem transform to
$$
\min_{\overline X} {\rm trace}(\overline X)\\
{\rm s.t.} \overline X \succeq 0\\
\overline{X}_{m+i,j} =\overline{X}_{j,m+i},i=1,...,n,j=1,...,m
$$
But $\overline{X}_{m+i,j} =\overline{X}_{j,m+i}$ seems can not writen as ${\rm trace}(A_i\overline{X})=b$,where $A_i$ symmetric matrice
This question comes form pape: A Rank Minimization Heuristic with Application to
Minimum Order System Approximation

Comment: Perhaps you need a numerical method to create an X-bar that is diagonalizeable ? Meaning you need to create A with a linear technique within a tolerance you choose, like SVD. I'm out of my depth here but I like to try and see the bigger picture.

Comment: SDP Solvers have an implicit constraint that the SDP matrix is symmetric, so no additional constraints are needed.  Your problem seems to be incomplete though, since the solutions is obviously $\bar{X}=0$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers If I add additional constraint $X \in C$,the solution seems is $\overline X =0$ too

Comment: In the complex case, the matrix is constrained to be Hermitian positive semidefinite.